# Amazon Web Services Geo Redundancy

Tags: amazon-web-services

I read that Azure has geo-redundant storage where data will have three copies synchronously created in the region and three copies asynchronously created in another geographic region for disaster recovery. I searched the web resources for AWS EBS storage but could not find any information for async geo-redundancy for EBS. Do they use another term for it or does AWS simply not have geo-redundant block storage?

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you read this?

Answer (score 3):

No public cloud provider that I'm aware of has geo-redundant block storage. (Google Cloud has [zone-redundant persistent disks though](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#repds).) You probably saw [geo-redundant blob/object storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy-grs?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json).

AWS has [S3 cross-region replication](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/03/amazon-s3-introduces-cross-region-replication/), but not a geo-redundant S3 storage class.

Comment: This is correct. They support replication for blob storage and file shares not disks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy

Comment: @BrandonMiller As far as I know, EBS corresponds to Azure page blob. And nowhere in the documents could I find a statement saying a sepcific type of storage is excempt from georeplication. Could you clarify please?

Comment: The table on that page says **Supported Storage Account Types** at the bottom and no there isnt quite and exact 1 to 1 mapping but EBS is more like managed disks https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/managed-disks/ and blob is more like s3